How to Export and Retrieve PostgreSQL Database from Coolify Cloud for Migration to Self-Hosted Server?
I am using Coolify Cloud to manage my Next.js application and PostgreSQL database. Both the application and the database are running in separate Docker containers.
I want to back up my PostgreSQL database and download it to my local machine so I can migrate to a self-hosted Coolify instance on my own server.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Using pg_dump to export the database. This works, but the backup file is stored on the Coolify Cloud server, and I am unable to retrieve it locally.
Attempting to connect to the PostgreSQL container from my local machine using pgAdmin 4, but it seems the database container is not accessible externally.
It looks like the Docker container hosting PostgreSQL is not exposed to the outside world.
My Questions:
How can I easily retrieve the database backup file from Coolify Cloud to my local machine?
Is there a way to configure the PostgreSQL container in Coolify Cloud to allow external connections (e.g., via pgAdmin)?
Are there alternative methods to achieve this migration?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
